# Shell Script to parse JTL/XML file to know if a specific node has a value

Tags: xml, shell, xslt, xml-parsing, jmeter

I have a JTL file which I need to parse to know if a node named < failure> has `true`, as its value.

I need to call a script file which should be able to make this decision in a `if` condition, based on which I need to do other actions. How do I implement the parsing of JTL/XML to know if a `failure-true` exists or not?

This JTL file has a lot of < failure> nodes in it.

Edit: I may be constructing all this wrong. All am trying is a shell script which will do a specific action if the JTL file it parsed has a node < failure> with value as `true`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<httpSample t="153" lt="152" ts="1434726402307" s="true" lb="xyz" dt="text" by="14"/>
<httpSample t="169" lt="169" ts="1434726402603" s="true" lb="asdasd" dt="text" by="471">
<assertionResult>
<name>Response Assertion</name>
<failure>false</failure>
<error>false</error>
</assertionResult>
</httpSample>
.
.
.
```

And so it continues

Comment: Can I ask why you need this? You need to decided whether to run a second test or not depending on the failure of first test?

Comment: Based on parsing result to know if failure node has value true in it, I have to  invoke RESTful calls to few applications.  This parsing needs to be done throughout the file if there is atleast one failure=true, I need to do that REST call

Comment: I am looking into Xmllint and Xpath. I am searching for a condition which says if you find atleast one failure = true, return some 'yes' or some kind of result

Comment: I'm not talking about the solution just yet, I'm asking about the need to do this. your JTL file is created as a result of a jmeter test, and you're using that in the start of a second jmeter test?

Comment: I am parsing JTL's in order to know if they have any failed test cases. If yes, I should do xyz.... Else do abc...   It wont be used at start of any other jmeter tests

Comment: Why not just `grep` for `<failure>true</failure>` ? Why do you have to parse xml?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81660/discussion-between-anuj-balan-and-rage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` for `<failure>true</failure>` in the .jtl file.

```
if grep -q <failure>true</failure> file.jtl; then
    echo found
else
    echo not found
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about which node has the value then this can be accomplished with grep.

```
if grep -q '<failure>true<\/failure>' jmeter-test.jtl ;then
   echo "FAILURE"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The safe way to do this is with an XML-aware tool:

```
failure=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//assertionResult/failure' -v . -n <jmeter-test.jtl)
if [[ $failure = true ]]; then
  echo "failed"
else
  echo "success"
fi
```

Unlike the naive `grep` approach, this only recognizes `failure` if it's in the right place -- under an `assertionResult` and not in a comment, not in text taken from a program's output, etc.